# How to make VBScript copy permissions along with files

Tags: windows, vbscript, permissions, windows-xp

This is all in Windows XP utilizing VBScript.

I have a directory with several files inside.  The files have varying permissions set.  I need to be able to copy the files to a new directory while retaining the permissions.  Using the script below the copy works fine but the permissions are overwritten by the new parent folder.

I am aware of xcopy but I am unsure how to make it work within the script.  Using robocopy is a slight possibility but should be avoided if at all possible.  Other utilities are out of the question due to network contraints.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim CopyFromPath, CopyToPath  
Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0 
Const NO_OPTIONS = 0 
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE 

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")  
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(WINDOW_HANDLE,"Select folder to copy:",NO_OPTIONS,ssfDRIVES) 

if (not objFolder is nothing) then 
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self  
    CopyFromPath = objFolderItem.Path 
else  
    Set objShell = nothing 
    WScript.Quit(0) 
end if 

Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(WINDOW_HANDLE, "Where should the folder be copied to?:", NO_OPTIONS, ssfDRIVES)  
if (not objFolder is nothing) then 
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self  
    CopyToPath = objFolderItem.Path 
else  
    Set objShell = nothing 
    WScript.Quit(0) 
end if 

Set objFolder = nothing 
Set objFolderItem = nothing 
Set objShell = nothing 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
objFSO.CopyFile CopyFromPath & "\*.*", CopyToPath & "\", OverwriteExisting 
msgbox "The folder has now been copied to " & CopyToPath
```

Answer (score 0):

[xcopy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323007) is a good idea for it. 
An example to how make it work within vbscript.

```
Set oWSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWSHShell.Exec "xcopy C:\source C:\destination /O /X /H /K /Y"
Set oWSHShell = Nothing
```